# c++ problem, maybe with types

Tags: c++

I have a little problem in my code. The variables don't want to change their values. Can you say why?
Here is my code:

```
vector<coordinate> rocks(N);
double angle;
double x, y;
// other code
while (x > 1.0 || x < -1.0 || y > 1.0 || y < -1.0) {
    angle = rand() * 2.0 * M_PI;
    cout << angle << endl;
    cout << rocks[i - 1].x << endl;
    cout << rocks[i - 1].y << endl;
    x = rocks[i-1].x + r0 * cos(angle);
    y = rocks[i-1].y + r0 * sin(angle);
    cout << x << endl;
    cout << y << endl << endl;
}
// other code
```

And the result on the console is:
6.65627e+09
0.99347
0.984713
1.09347
0.984713

1.16964e+09
0.99347
0.984713
1.09347
0.984713

As you see the values of x, y variables doesn't change and this while be an infinity loop. What's the problem? What do you think?

Comment: What are `angle`, `x`, and `y` equal to when you get to the while loop? What is `i`?

Comment: Thanks for the -1... :) I didn't know that stupid people will be degraded... :)

Comment: +2/-2 is +6 reputation, so at least it's good that way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why are you expeciting `x` and `y` to change? You assign to them the value of a calculation that doesn't change?

`rand() * 2.0 * M_PI` is always a multiple of 2 * pi (as far as a double can represent) so `cos(angle)` will be 1 and `sin(angle)` will be 0.

Comment: Yes. The C standard rand function returns ints, not doubles.

Comment: +1 on this one.  Basically, I think the original user is expecting rand() to return between 0 and 1 floating point, not 0 to RAND_MAX as is stated here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/

Comment: Yes, the `int` returned by `rand()` will be promoted to a `double` when multiplied by `2.0`.

Comment: Changing that to `(rand() * 2.0) / RAND_MAX * M_PI` will get you an angle between 0 and 2 * M_PI.

Comment: There are assignments to both x and y.  The problem (with those not changing) is also that `i` isn't changing.

Comment: And don't forget to call `srand()` first.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your rand() function isn't defined. Sometimes failing to include the correct headers results in an odd default rand being called, and it may always return the same number. This is just off the top of my head, but I would check in that direction.

Actually, I don't ever remember this happening with rand, but I think I've seen it happen with the trigonometric functions if you don't include math.h. Though that may be a compiler specific quirk.

Answer (score 0):

`angle` you are generating seems to be extremely large.  I'm assuming you want to generate `angle` between `0` and `2*pi`.  Check to see if `rand()` is returning a number between 0 to 1 and also check to see what `M_PI` is.

If that doesn't help, find out what each elements are by adding more `cout`